# How to dump data with schema in SQLite?

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I am using SQLit3# with java and I want dump my schema with data to some xyz folder on desktop in sql format.I know dump will work but I dont know how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this:

```
sqlite3 db .dump
```